# Facebook on Blackberry app

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I have noticed that in BB app, when I click on  share info via fb option, it is taking me to browser fb app, Is there any app which will take the user to native FB app on clicking share?

Thanks in Advance,
Vadivelan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no app which will integrate with the Facebook app in the Blackberry to share.